# Expecations and variance proofs

Tags: statistics

If $0\leq X\leq a$, show that

(a) $E[X^2] \leq a E[X]$

(b) $Var(X)\leq E[X](a - E[X] )$

(c) $Var(X)\leq a^2/4$

Attempted proof a.) Based on Clement comment since $0\leq X \leq a$ then we have that $0\leq X^2 = X\cdot X \leq a X$. So, \begin{align*}
0\leq E[X]\leq a \Rightarrow 0\leq E[X^2]\leq aE[X]
\end{align*}

Attempted proof b.) We have $$Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$$ Since from a.) $E[X^2] \leq a E[X]$ then it follows that $$Var(X) \leq E[X](a - E[X])$$

Attempted proof c.) Let $f(x) = x(a - x)$ on $[0,a]$. We see that $f(x)$ has a maximum of $a^2/4$ when $x = a/2$. Now, note that $\mathbb{E}[X]\in [0,a]$. From part (b), we showed that $Var[X]\leq f(\mathbb{E}[X])$ and we know that $f(x)\leq f(a/2) = a^2/4$ for all $x\in [0,a]$. Now, since $$f(\mathbb{E}[X]) = \mathbb{E}(a - \mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \frac{a^2}{2}$$ then it must be the case from (b) that $$Var[X]\leq \frac{a^2}{4}$$
I am not sure how to prove c.) or a.) any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56394/discussion-on-question-by-wolfgang-1-expecations-and-variance-proofs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), let's use the definition of expected value. Note $E[X^2] = \sum {{x_i}^2 * p(x_i)}$, and $E[x] = \sum {x_i * p(x_i)}$. Consider what happens when you multiply the sum form of $E[X]$ by $a$.

Comment: Not really sure if that helps but thanks anyways

Comment: What happens when you multiply the sum by $a$? You then get $\sum {a * x_i * p(x_i)}$. As $a * x_i \geq x_i ^2$, the result follows. Does this make sense?